# How do I program a share button ? xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, whatsapp

I found a repository on gifthub that is exactly what i was looking for. Can you help me how to code this to work with a single button. I don't enough experience yet with ios programmin to do this. I almost finished building my first app, but i need help with this.

Thanks in advance

https://github.com/BobDG/BDGShare

Comment: any answer found for this question help me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a beginner I suggest this..
Its much easier. Just a few lines of code.

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"shareButton pressed");
    NSString *texttoshare = @"text to share";
    UIImage *imagetoshare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"beck.png"];
    NSArray *activityItems = @[texttoshare, imagetoshare];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can I do this instead ?
UIImage *imagetoshare = self.imageView.image
    ;

Comment: Can you please check out the project in the link provided. I assing my photo but It doesn't send when i click WhatsApp share icon. PLease help me

Comment: excluded UIActivityTypePostToWeibo lol